# How to get version number in registry and install new software using batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to check the current version of Muvizu in the registery and then if it equals the latest version don't do anything if not install a new version. I would like this to run from batch.

I have looked at some websites such as this one :

http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/113643-batch-file-that-check-version-in-registry/

but I'm struggling to adapt the code and get it working.

The register setting that needs to be queried is : 
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Muvizu
and the node is DisplayValue and the value of the latest version is 2013.10.25.01R

so essentially I need some wizzy batch code that will do the following:

Check regkey, 
if regkey display version = 2013.10.25.01r, do nothing,
else,
run installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set regkey="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Muvizu" /v DisplayValue
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('reg query %regkey%^|Find "DisplayValue"') do (
  if errorlevel 1 ( 
     REM Run installer
     goto :eof   
  )
  if "%%a" NEQ "2013.10.25.01r" (
    REM Run installer
  ) ELSE (
    Echo You have the most recent version of Muvizu
  )
)
```

Comment: Hi matt,
That works a treat however if muvizu is not installed (i.e the key is not there) the script errors saying the key is not found. Is it possible to catch this error and run the installer ?

Comment: Thanks.... I think that worked ok, but I kinda tweaked to do some other bits, but it was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work as you have described.

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Muvizu" |find /i "2013.10.25.01R" >nul || installer.exe
```